# pytz - Converting UTC and timezone to local time

Tags: python, timezone, utc, pytz

I have a `datetime` in utc time zone, for example:

```
utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

And a pytz timezone object:

```
tz = timezone('America/St_Johns')
```

What is the proper way to convert `utc_time` to the given timezone?

Comment: related: [How to convert a python utc datetime to a local datetime using only python standard library?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4563272/4279)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
pytz.utc.localize(utc_time, is_dst=None).astimezone(tz)
```

This line first converts the naive (time zone unaware) `utc_time` `datetime` object to a `datetime` object that contains a timezone (UTC). Then it uses the [`astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) function to adjust the time according to the requested time zone.

Comment: `utc_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(tz)`. Note: `pytz.utc` is a special case (zero utc offset, always). You don't need `localize()` call in this case. If you do keep it (for generality); then add `tz.normalize()` call around the expression ([it might be necessary if the source timezone is not UTC](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic)).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian the call to `localize` is needed because `utc_time` doesn't contain timezone information. Without it `astimezone` won't work.

Comment: @Tzach what do you think the `replace()` call does in my previous comment?

Comment: It works also for utc_timestamp as int with datetime.utcfromtimestamp(utc_timestamp), which returns a timezone not aware datetime object. But utc_time.replace doesn't do the time schift and only add a tzinfo.

Comment: @YingdingWang The question from almost 5 years ago is not using `utcfromtimestamp`. Also `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` sets tzinfo as None.

Comment: `localize` is about 7% slower than `replace` (which is also the example used in the docs)

Comment: Use `fromutc` (see [@user8808265's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46979496/4653485)).

Answer (score 29):

It's the exact purpose of [`fromutc`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.fromutc) function:

```
tz.fromutc(utc_time)
```

(`astimezone` function calls `fromutc` under the hood, but tries to convert to UTC first, which is unneeded in your case)

Answer (score 12):

I agree with Tzach's answer. Just wanted to include that the is_dst parameter is not required:

```
pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow()).astimezone(tz)
```

That code converts the current UTC time to a timezone aware current datetime.

Whereas the code below converts the current UTC time to a timezone aware datetime which is not necessarily current. The timezone is just appended into the UTC time value.

```
tz.localize(datetime.utcnow())
```

Comment: If you already have a timezone-aware datetime, then you just need to use `astimezone`: `dt.astimezone(tz)`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18862958/648162) and the [pytz docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz).

Comment: user8808265's answer is much simpler.

Answer (score 8):

May I recommend to use [arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow)? If I understood the question:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> utc = arrow.utcnow()
>>> utc
<Arrow [2014-08-12T13:01:28.071624+00:00]>    
>>> local = utc.to("America/St_Johns")
>>> local
<Arrow [2014-08-12T10:31:28.071624-02:30]>
```

---

You can also use

```
tz.fromutc(utc_time)
```

Comment: Thank you. This library indeed looks as a good alternative to `datetime`, however my project is big and I don't want to create more confusion by using another date-time library. I will definitely consider using it in other projects.

Answer (score 5):

Another very easy way:

Because `utcnow` method returns a **naive** object, so you have to convert  the **naive** object into **aware** object.  Using `replace` method you can convert a **naive** object into **aware** object. Then you can use the `astimezone` method to create new datetime object in a different time zone.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz    
utc_time = datetime.utcnow()
tz = pytz.timezone('America/St_Johns')

utc_time =utc_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) #replace method      
st_john_time=utc_time.astimezone(tz)        #astimezone method
print(st_john_time)
```

Comment: replace method is a bad idea. It is random in its behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the sample below, I use it for similar task

```
tz = pytz.timezone('America/St_Johns')
time_difference=tz.utcoffset(utc_time).total_seconds() #time difference between UTC and local timezones in 5:30:00 format
utc_time = date + timedelta(0,time_difference)
```

It works fast and you don't need to import additional libraries.

Comment: This is wrong for timezones with daylight savings, because it doesn't account for them. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18862958/648162).