# Using pytz TImezones for discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, timezone, discord, discord.py, pytz

How can i get the `guild.created_at` time in the `Europe/Berlin` timezone?
i tried `guild.created_at.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))` and its doesnt work. i also tried other forums, tutorials and the docs, but with no success.

I've already looked at the options:

[pytz localize vs datetime replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379740/pytz-localize-vs-datetime-replace)

http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

[pytz - Converting UTC and timezone to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264811/pytz-converting-utc-and-timezone-to-local-time/25265611)

Comment: `guild.created_at` returns creation time in UTC as `datetime.datetime`. See answer here (`pytz` example): https://stackoverflow.com/a/13287083/9083371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the fromutc function:

```
pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin').fromutc(guild.created_at)
```

Comment: `pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin').fromutc(guild.created_at)
NameError: name 'pytz' is not defined`

Comment: You'll need to import the pytz package like you did before.

Comment: With `timezone('Europe/Berlin').fromutc(guild.created_at)` it worked in my Case