# Why are these datetime objects timezones not equal?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I'm having a problem with `datetime` objects. Here's my code:

```
import datetime
import pytz

userInfo = 'Europe/Istanbul'

# Current date, 2020-9-8 15:00
cd = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone(userInfo))

# Example date, 2020-9-8 15:00
ed = datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 8, 15, 0, pytz.timezone(userInfo))

# Print both dates
print('Example', ed, '\n', 'Current', cd, '\n')

if ed == cd:
    print('Equal')
else:
    print('Not worked')
```

As you can see these dates are equal but when I try to print them it gives me this result:

```
Example 2020-9-8 15:00:00.000000+01:56
Current 2020-9-8 15:00:00.000000+03:00
Not worked
```

Timezones are different, why? I'm using same timezone for both objects. How to set timezone as `+03:00` (which is *Istanbul's timezone*) for both objects? Thanks.

Comment: An argument is missing for datetime.datetime. At the place where the timezone info is it should be the microseconds, after that it's the timezone info.

Comment: see [this resource](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html) to find out why... just use `dateutil` instead to avoid such weird behavior. Or `zoneinfo` once Python 3.9 is out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can't work, because you need to use tzinfo=... :

```
ed = datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 8, 15, 0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone(userInfo))
```

But it gives wrong result. I don't know why, but to get what you want, use this form:

```
ed = pytz.timezone(userInfo).localize(datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 8, 15, 0))
```

For more info take a look at this post: [pytz - Converting UTC and timezone to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264811/pytz-converting-utc-and-timezone-to-local-time)